# What does it mean "One year after the rings"

Tags: meaning

Is there any place to recommend to help to look up the phase unknown?
Like below:

```
One year after the rings 
and a west coast honeymoon 
We are living in a rented house 
with a terrible view....
```

Does it mean one year after their marriage ? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.

*The rings* refers to the rings that were presumably exchanged at the wedding ceremony that preceded the west coast honeymoon.  By extension, *the rings* refers to the wedding ceremony itself.

Comment: +1 It really helps me. I will be careful for to ask this kind of question. I am not some lyric interpreter. I am just an English learner. You can check my historical questions.  Thanks your kindly understanding. Hope you have a nice day.

Comment: I always think English SE is a very good place to improve my English. I do have a lot of reading in my everyday. including News, Article , Post, Books, Somethings I listen to the English songs. Thanks your help. Please forgive me ask this kind of question.

Answer (score 0):

*The rings* has no specific meaning, other than to refer to a roughly circular shape.  Thus one *must* interpret the meaning based on context.  In the above context which makes more sense:

- Boxing matches inside a "boxing ring"?
- Rings around the bathtub?
- The phone ringing?
- The exchange of rings in a wedding ceremony?

There is no "right" answer here (and it is not that unusual, especially in poetry, to be "led down the garden path" to the wrong conclusion).  Rather, based on your experience and understanding of the context, you must select what you feel is *probably* the correct meaning.

Comment: I guess it means the wedding. because the second sentence mentioned the word `honeymoon`. It means the couple is married. and they are on their `honeymoon` after one year's marriage. Thanks.